# Not obeying changes to HOSTS file

Tags: windows, configuration, hosts-file

Suppose `example.com` points to `1.2.3.4` IP address.

I want to be able to put `something.example.com` in my Windows hosts file so that it goes to another IP address. I've defined it as such in the hosts file.

`9.8.7.6    something.example.com`

When I ping `something.example.com` I still get `1.2.3.4` and when I visit the URL, it still resolves the website on `1.2.3.4` instead of from where I want, `9.8.7.6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you place your hosts file in: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc with this syntax:

> 102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com

Comment: Also, you must be administrator to save it, so if windows 7: Click Start – search for “Notepad“, right-click and select “Run as Administrator“ then open the hosts file

Comment: The actual issue was, I had to restart my computer. :-/ Strange but true.

Comment: That's a little odd, host file changes should take immediately. Though a cached DNS lookup may take precedence. Did you try ipconfig /flushdns ?

Comment: The hosts file should take effect immediately and entries in the hosts file should replace matching entries in the DNS resolver cache upon saving the hosts file. I'm pretty sure that running ipconfig/flushdns will preload the DNS resolver cache with entries from the hosts file along with clearing the DNS resolver cache of entries not contained in the hosts file.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the local resolver cache is queried first? Does running 'ipconfig /flushdns' perhaps resolve the issue?